# Command gh issue list to export issues to CSV file

Tags: csv, jq, export-to-csv, github-cli, github-issues

this command

```
gh issue list --limit 10000 --state all --json number,title,assignees,state,labels,url |^
jq -r '["number","title","assignees","state","labels","url"],^
       (.[] | [.number, .title,^
               (.assignees | if length==0 then "Unassigned" else map(.login)|join(",") end),^
               .state,^
               (.labels | map(.name)|join(",")),^
               .url^
              ]^
       ) | @csv' > issues-$(date '+%Y-%m-%d').csv
```

returns the following error

`.number not recognized as an internal or external command operable program or batch file`

Any idea?

I tried the command from cli and from .bat: same behavior

Comment: What are those `^` doing?

Comment: `^` are `.bat` file equivalent of `"\"` unix shell line continuation chars. Good luck to all.

Comment: Why not put your `jq` script in a file and avoid what is obviously a quoting issue? (Nice code! ). Good luck.